# Displaying JSON Data in Angular Component

Tags: angular

I have a service that is getting data from the server

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class CardService {

    private url = "http://192.168.100.112:8080/angular";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCards(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
 }
}
```

And it works fine with my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CardService } from '../../services/card.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'cards-list',
    templateUrl: './card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
  })
  export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  private cardData: any;

  constructor(private svc: CardService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.svc.getCards().subscribe(data =>{
      this.cardData = data;
      console.log(this.cardData)
    })
  }
}
```

The console is displaying the data I am trying to show on the app.component.html

but the data is not being displayed on the website:

appcomponent.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <cards-list></cards-list>
</div>
```

card.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="cardData">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let card of cardData">
       <span>{{card.name}}</span>
       <span>{{card.id}}</span>
       <span>{{card.progress}}</span>
       <span>{{card.issue}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I forgot to write that before, I updated the question.

Comment: ``cardData`` is an array of JSON ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I added my console log information

Comment: change `private cardData: any;` to `private cardData:any[] = [];`. May this help you

Comment: @Fix3r , your data is a simple object . You cannot loop over a simple object

Comment: Your cardData will be multiple or single ?

Comment: multiple. I will have more than one card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngFor` required an array for loop through. Response coming as an object. make carddata an array and push the response object.

```
  private cardData: any = [];

  constructor(private svc: CardService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.svc.getCards().subscribe(data =>{
      this.cardData.push(data);
      console.log(this.cardData)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Your first suggestion was       this.cardData = [data]; and it worked great. What is the different now? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka, this will fail if API returns the multiple objects in a form of list next time.

Comment: if it return an array no need to push. just assign the array object to carddata, it all depend on the response type

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka using the suggested code and based on what you and Prachi said I got it working. Thank you guys

Answer (score 3):

This code will not work for a single object. You need to return the array even if the record length is 1.

```
<div *ngIf="cardData">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let card of cardData">
       <span>{{card.name}}</span>
       <span>{{card.id}}</span>
       <span>{{card.progress}}</span>
       <span>{{card.issue}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It actually can return more than one object as well

Comment: Then you need to change your API, not your code. Change your API to return data in the form of list, even if the record length is 1. Currently, if record length is 1, its returning object, instead of array of objects.

Comment: What do you mean?
On the code, I have now an array with two json objects. The solution suggested above only works for one, as stated before.

Comment: I stated the same. Use your angular code only and make changes in API in case of record length 1.

Answer (score -2):

Define, private cardData: any[]=[];